# Добавление шорткода через js

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

Всем привет!
Проблема такая, пытаюсь вставить в функцию шорткод, чтобы при вызове функции использовался данный шорткод.
Вот что я сделал, создал функцию

```
function test() {
  document.querySelector("#filters").innerHTML = ` <?php echo do_shortcode('[site_reviews_summary assigned_posts="705" schema="true" hide="bars" class="rating-school"]');?>`;
}
```

но при вызове функции test, php просто оборачивается в комментарии и ничего не срабатывает

```
<!--?php echo do_shortcode('[site_reviews_summary assigned_posts="705" schema="true" hide="bars" class="rating-school"]');?-->
```

Как можно вывести шорткод через js?

Comment: Ваша идея и код бессмысленны, так работать не будет.
Вы же в курсе, php работает на стороне сервера и возвращает html?
Так вот, когда приходит уже готовый html, вы пытаетесь всунуть ему ваш "шорткод".
Советую хорошенько поучить основы Wordpress, а еще лучше основы PHP и Javascript.

Comment: [Ошибка молотка](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/709/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-xy/710#710)

Comment: Получить содержимое шорт кода через fetch а потом вставить в элемент

Comment: @Walfter А как это сделать?

Comment: Добавить роут который будет обрабатывать этот шорткод на сервере, потом на клиенте получить отрендеренные сервером данные и вывести в элемент

Comment: @Walfter можно какой-то пример?

Comment: С вордпрессом давно работал, там есть обработчик wp_ajax насколько помню вешаеться через хуки, повешайте своё правлио на него, в нём обработайте шорткод, и получите на клиенте

Comment: А в чем проблема? Почему нельзя нормально отрисовать этот шорткод как положено через PHP?

Comment: @fortavey данные в том числе и шорткод подгружается через js

Answer (score 0):

Никак. PHP выполняется на сервере, после чего отдает страницу браузеру, где уже выполняются скрипты. Засунуть кусок кода на PHP внутрь скрипта JS нельзя